# C# Lambda with diferent levels in object

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to do a lambda, with an object, but I have the conditions in different levels of object.

the object serialized into xml just to show to you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSegment>
    <Segment>
    <Legs>
      <Leg>
        <FlightDesignator>
          <CarrierCode >G3</CarrierCode>
          <FlightNumber >1040</FlightNumber>
        </FlightDesignator>
      </Leg>
    </Legs>
    <PaxSegments >
      <PaxSegment>
        <LiftStatus>Boarded</LiftStatus>
      </PaxSegment>
      <PaxSegment>
        <LiftStatus>CheckedIn</LiftStatus>
      </PaxSegment>
    </PaxSegments>
    </Segment>  

    <Segment>
    <Legs>
      <Leg>
        <FlightDesignator>
          <CarrierCode >G3</CarrierCode>
          <FlightNumber >1016</FlightNumber>
        </FlightDesignator>
      </Leg>
    </Legs>
    <PaxSegments >
      <PaxSegment>
        <LiftStatus>Boarded</LiftStatus>
      </PaxSegment>
      <PaxSegment>
        <LiftStatus>CheckedIn</LiftStatus>
      </PaxSegment>
    </PaxSegments>
    </Segment>  
</ArrayOfSegment>
```

What I have to do is get the segments with `"FlightNumber" == 1016` and the `"LiftStatus" == "Boarded"`, but they are in different levels of xml.

Can some lambda expert help me?

Comment: This question will probably be easier to answer if you show your C# type definitions, rather than the serialized instances.

Comment: I guess something like `segments.Where(s => s.Legs.Any(l =>l.FlightDesignator.FlightNumber == 1016) && s.PaxSegments.Any(p => p.LiftStatus == "Boarded"))` But it would be better if you include the class definitions instead, unless you are doing Linq-To-XML which would be something different as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I try to answer your question, I'd like you to confirm that these types match pretty well to what you have in your C# class hierarchy:

```
public class Segment
{
    public List<Leg> Legs { get; set; }
    public List<PaxSegment> PaxSegments { get; set; }
}
public class Leg
{
    public FlightDesignator FlightDesignator { get; set; }
}
public class FlightDesignator
{
    public string CarrierCode { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }
}
public class PaxSegment
{
    public string LiftStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Second, I'm inferring from your XML that this is the list of segments you're working with:

```
var segments = new List<Segment>
{
    new Segment
    {
        Legs = new List<Leg>
        {
            new Leg {
                FlightDesignator = new FlightDesignator{
                    CarrierCode = "G3",
                    FlightNumber = "1040"
                }
            }
        },
        PaxSegments = new List<PaxSegment> {
            new PaxSegment { LiftStatus = "Boarded" },
            new PaxSegment { LiftStatus = "CheckedIn" }
        }
    },
    new Segment {
        Legs = new List<Leg>
        {
            new Leg{
                FlightDesignator=new FlightDesignator
                {
                    CarrierCode="G3",
                    FlightNumber="1016"
                }
            }
        },
        PaxSegments = new List<PaxSegment> {
            new PaxSegment { LiftStatus = "Boarded" },
            new PaxSegment { LiftStatus = "CheckedIn" }
        }
    }
};
```

If so, you can get the desired `Segment`s with the following query:

```
var desiredSegments = segments.Where(s
    => s.Legs.Any(l => l.FlightDesignator.FlightNumber == "1016")
    && s.PaxSegments.Any(ps => ps.LiftStatus == "Boarded")
);
```

However, your question is a little unclear, so if you're looking for the `PaxSegment`s of the corresponding `Segment`s, you can follow up with a `SelectMany` to get at them:

```
var desiredPaxSegments = segments
    .Where(s
        => s.Legs.Any(l => l.FlightDesignator.FlightNumber == "1016")
        && s.PaxSegments.Any(ps => ps.LiftStatus == "Boarded"))
    .SelectMany(s => s.PaxSegments);
```

Comment: Tomas Aschan, sorry about my unclear question, but you got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication75
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var status = doc.Descendants("Segment").Select(x => new
            {
                flightNumber = (string)x.Descendants("FlightNumber").FirstOrDefault(),
                carrierCode = (string)x.Descendants("CarrierCode").FirstOrDefault(),
                liftStatus = x.Descendants("LiftStatus").Select(y => (string)y).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }

    }
}
```